# Combining multiple OR operators with an AND operator

Tags: sql, mysqli, operators

I am having some difficulty writing a query that has multiple OR operators followed by and AND operator.

At present, my query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `contentvalues` WHERE (`contentid` = 16 OR `contentid` = 18) AND `value` <= 180;
```

However, the results produced seem to indicate that the AND operator:

```
AND `value` <= 180;
```

is being ignored.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong?

--MORE INFO--

An example of the table I am querying looks like:

- **contentid**, **value**
- 16, 200
- 18, 150
- 47, 120
- 16, 110

The expected results should be `18, 150` and `16, 110`, but `16, 200` is also being included, even though `200` is greater than `180`.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, above question is wrong - I tried to delete but cannot since it already has questions.

The problem wasnt the query, it was that some of the values in the `values` column were strings. These were showing no matter what the number in the query was.

Comment: The issue you describe is not [reproducible](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d4278/1). The predicates of the `WHERE` clause seem to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I think you made a typo: The expected results should be `18, 250`. I think you mean `18, 150`.

Comment: @EdwinStoteler yes I did, thanks

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes, I just realised my question was poorly written. I tried to delete but cannot since it has answers.

Comment: Actually you can delete it. I think delete is disabled only if an answer has been accepted.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos no  luck, I will re-write the question properly. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MeltingDog: `I will re-write the question properly` Still there is anything which is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your `or` logic for same variable in SQL **[`in`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)** clause.

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM `contentvalues` WHERE contentid in (16,18) AND value <= 180;
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the `WHERE` clause of the OP. It shouldn't produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

The results what you are getting is correct. I guess you are confused as to how your query is actually getting executed. So your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `contentvalues` WHERE (`contentid` = 16 OR `contentid` = 18) AND `value` <= 180;
```

which is like taking the

```
`contentid` = 16 AND `value` <= 180   //gives 16, 110
```

UNION

```
OR `contentid` = 18 AND `value` <= 180   //gives 18, 150
```

So the expected result is correct.

> but 16, 200 is also being included, even though 200 is greater than 180.

It is not ignored, its just that it is not fulfilling the `where` clause condition.

Answer (score 0):

If values in the column are string then you can use 
SELECT * FROM `contentvalues` WHERE contentid in (16,18) AND 
CONVERT(value, SIGNED INTEGER) <= 180;